# VIM visual block sort numerically using Vissort

Tags: sorting, vim

I need help using the Vissort plugin to visual block sort numberically.
The [documentation](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/doc/vissort.txt.html) states that I can use the 'VSO n' command to set sort to 'n' for numeric but I'm having no success.

I'm on a windows machine.

The below example only has one column, but in the real world I need to be able to numerically sort on any column within a text file. For now my work around is using '!gsort.exe -k 10 -n' to sort by the 10th column.

After using 'VSO n' and running Vissort, this is how my list is sorted:

```
1 
11
13
15
17
19
2 
21
23
25
27
29
3 
31
33
35
37
39
```

Comment: How did you select the lines? Was only the first column selected? `:sort n` would also work if you selected these lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU `sort`. First select visual block and then:

```
:'<,'>!sort -k 1 -n
```

Comment: The vissort plugin sorts only a single column, and leaves the other columns as-is. Whereas your solution would sort all columns, based on the selected key column.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks, I didn't know about. However, GNU `sort` will work for OPs data.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about Vissort. I know of other workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `:VSO` option only applies to the `:Vissort` command, not to `:'<,'>B sort`.

So, either of these should work:

```
:VSO n
:'<,'>Vissort
```

or

```
:'<,'>B sort n
```

Comment: VSO n has no effect on the Vissort sort.

Comment: Well, it does for me :-) `:VSO` should affect the `g:vissort_option` variable, does it for you? To further troubleshoot, you'd probably have to debug the plugin.